Filtered dataframe not correct
I try to filter a dataframe using the following expression:  I am seeking the times "col" changes to "val":
filtered_df = df[(df[col]== val) & (df.shift(1)[col] != df[col])]

df is a dataframe that is generated by a function:
df= create_df(data)

The filtered_df is empty even though their condition is verified at least one time in my data.
When I try to export my df to a csv file:
data = pd.to_csv("out")

then
Apply the above filter to data, it works, I get a non-empty dataframe.
I don't know how to explain this, df and data are meant to be the same.
Example: let's say df is:
Index  col
  0     4
  1     5
  2     7
  3     5

The expected result if val=5 is:
df_filtered =  1 5
               3 5

Any help please? Thanks

The best way to explain data is to show it. Please, provide [mre] with a data sample, the output you get, and the output you expect.

@YevhenKuzmovych, I edited the post with an example , thank you!

pd.to_csv() doesn't return anything when it writes to a file. So data will be None.

i think there is a typo. Do you want df_filtered.to_csv("out") ? and not pd

I use pd.to_csv just to store mydataframe in a csv file then I read it from there using pd.read_csv. Then I apply the filter. When I do this I get a non empty dataframe and it works. But when I apply the filter to the resulted dataframe directly it does not work

df = pd.DataFrame({'col': [4, 5, 7, 5]}) then filtered_df = df[(df['col']== val) & (df.shift(1)['col'] != df['col'])] produces the desired result in filtered_df.

Hello,
I solved this,  The filter returns None value because when I careated my dataframe using create_df(data) I stored my "float" values in a non valid format hence the filter couldn't apply because the type is not valid. I used  df[col].astype(float) to convert my data to the right format.

This question is similar to: pandas how to check dtype for all columns in a dataframe?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

I solved this. The filter returned None value because when I created my dataframe using create_df(data), I stored my "float" values in a non-valid format; hence the filter couldn't apply because the type was not valid. I used df[col].astype(float) to convert my data to the right format.

I order to filter I used following code.
import pandas as pd
data = {'Index': [0,1,2,3],
        'col': [4,5,7,5]}
# Create DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
#output
 Index  col
0      0    4
1      1    5
2      2    7
3      3    5

df_filtered = df[df['col'] == 5]  
print('\nResult dataframe :\n', df_filtered) 
Result dataframe :
#output
    Index  col
1      1    5
3      3    5
# to create csv
df_filtered.to_csv("out")

